# React Server Rendering causing a flash after server render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

Server rendering works OK in development, but there is a white flash on the screen in production. Here is an app where the issue is happening https://github.com/robertfordso/react-test

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions! You can comment on that other one or differentiate your own.

Comment: @jakerella thanks. I added a repository now of the app that has the problem. As it can be a specific mistake I made in the code, I don't think it's duplicate of the other question anymore.

Comment: Hi, did you find why is it flashing? Thanks!